# Mix input/output with Ruby IO?

Tags: ruby, io, console

I am hoping to write a small method that can interact with a subprocess (`bash` in this case) and should be able to both *write* commands and have those commands print their outback back to my shell when running the Ruby file.

So far, I can do something similar with this code:

```rb
require 'io/console'
@shell = IO.popen('/bin/bash', 'w')
def run(command)
  puts command
  @shell.puts command
  puts 'Done'
end
run 'var=3'
run 'echo $var'
run 'sleep 2'
run 'ls docs'

@shell.close
```

And then when I run this code all of the Ruby code is printed first, and only later does any of the shell code get printed:

```
var=3
Done
echo $var
Done
sleep 2
Done
ls docs
Done
3
<ls output>
```

I was trying to read some of the tests for `io/console` as I'm almost certain there exists a really straightforward way to interact with a subprocess like this and get the output inline with the commands being run:
https://github.com/ruby/io-console/blob/master/test/io/console/test_io_console.rb

Comment: Maybe you want [#popen3](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.1/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3)?

Comment: `@shell.puts command` doesn't wait for the command to finish. Your script is probably done generating input before bash has started interpreting and executing it.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs Do you have an example where I can continue to send commands to the same `popen3` and have the output displayed in realtime?

Comment: @Stefan I can wait until I `close` the shell to see the output printed out. Is there a way  I can wait on the `popen` object returned after _each_ command?

Comment: @StevenHepting but wait for what? `var=3` doesn’t generate any output, nor does `sleep 2`.

Comment: @Stefan Right. I'd like a generic function that can run a command and make sure the output prints out for the user right away (if there is any output). I've only been able to interleave commands with printing if I know there is going to be output. It will deadlock otherwise. Something like this, but it fails if I try to print lines when there's no output     ```stdin.puts 'var=3'
    stdin.puts 'echo $var'
    debug stdout.gets
    stdin.puts 'aws --version'
    debug stdout.gets
    stdin.puts 'ls docs'
    debug stdout.gets
    stdin.puts 'aws --version'
    debug stdout.gets```

Comment: Why do you need this kind of interaction? What is the script supposed to achieve? Is this for automation, testing, or something else?

Comment: @Stefan this is to run `nix-shell` when sets up an environment with specific binaries and tools available in `PATH` but needs 1-2 seconds to get it fully set up. So if I want to run 1000 fast-running commands in that shell the overhead is too much to set up each time. I'd like to start it up once, and then run the 1000 commands in the same process just as if I was typing them in directly.